# Is there any way to match and remove logical operator from Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex

I don't want to include Logical operators(and, or, not) while using Match function in Regex.
I tried below but it doesn't worked as expected. can someone please help me.

Sort of strings I am using for parsing :
Example :

```
1. Input -->'(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0'
Output --> ["Value1", "Value2"]

2. Input : 'Value_1'
Output -->["Value_1"]

3. Input : '(Value_1 * Value_2)'
Output : ["Value1", "Value2"]

4. Input : 'Value_Machine_Outcome==4?1:0'
Output : Value_Machine_Outcome
```

**Nested conditions : No**

**Are the conditions always in brackets : No**
I am evaluating them in very next step using **Math.evaluate**

Please have example below :

```js
const paragraph = '(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?<!and|or|not)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);

// expected output: Array ["Value1", "Value2"]
```

Comment: Are the conditions always conveniently in `()` like that?

Comment: @anubhava - It's in the question (comment in the code).

Comment: Can you explain more about what sort of strings are you parsing? Can you have nested conditions? Are the conditions always in brackets? Can you share more examples? As a side note, ysually such strings are consumed using a parser as it can more easily handle a variety of situations that might be problematic using regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your updated question completely changes the nature of the inputs. If the inputs are that varied, you'll need to match just about any "word" that doesn't start with a digit that isn't `and`, `or`, or `not` (but that fits with your original attempt, so I guess that makes sense):

```
const regex = /(?!and|or|not)\b[A-Z]\w*/gi;
```

Live Example:

```js
const tests = [
    {
        str: "(Value1==6) and or not (Value2==0)?1:0",
        expect: ["Value1", "Value2"]
    },
    {
        str: "Value_1",
        expect: ["Value_1"]
    },
    {
        str: "(Value_1 * Value_2)",
        expect: ["Value_1", "Value_2"]
    },
    {
        str: "Value_Machine_Outcome==4?1:0",
        expect: ["Value_Machine_Outcome"] // Note I put this in an array
    }
];

const regex = /(?!and|or|not)\b[A-Z]\w*/gi;
for (const {str, expect} of tests) {
    const result = str.match(regex);
    const good = result.length === expect.length && result.every((v, i) => v === expect[i]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result), good ? "Ok" : "<== ERROR");
}
```

That works by disallowing `and`, `or`, and `not`, and requiring a match at a word boundary (`\b`).
Note that in the tests, I changed the expected result of the `Value_Machine_Outcome==4?1:0` string to be an array, not just a string, like all the others.

---

**Original Answer** before the question completely changed the inputs:

If you want to use `String.prototype.match`, you can use a positive look-behind (since ES2018) for a `(` and match everything prior to a `=` following it:

```
const regex = /(?<=\()[^=]+/g;
```

Live Example:

```js
const paragraph = '(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /(?<=\()[^=]+/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);

// expected output: Array ["Value1", "Value2"]
```

If you're okay with a loop, you can avoid the lookbehind (since they were only added in ES2018) by using a capture group:

```
const regex = /\(([^=]+)/g;
const found = [];
let match;
while (!!(match = regex.exec(paragraph))) {
    found.push(match[1]);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const paragraph = '(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /\(([^=]+)/g;
const found = [];
let match;
while (!!(match = regex.exec(paragraph))) {
    found.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(found);

// expected output: Array ["Value1", "Value2"]
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> My expression can also contain underscore. like it could be value_1, value_2. Will it work there ?

and I said it would because both of the above match anything but a `=`.

Later you said:

> when my structure contain 'Value_1' it ignores

Again, both of the above work just fine with `Value_1` and `Value_2`:

First:

```js
const paragraph = '(Value_1==6) and (Value_2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /(?<=\()[^=]+/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);

// expected output: Array ["Value1", "Value2"]
```

Second:

```js
const paragraph = '(Value_1==6) and (Value_2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /\(([^=]+)/g;
const found = [];
let match;
while (!!(match = regex.exec(paragraph))) {
    found.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(found);

// expected output: Array ["Value1", "Value2"]
```

Comment: Probmlem if you have nested conditions like `((Value1==6) and (Value2==0))?1:0`  - the result is `(Value1` and `Value2`

Comment: @VLAZ - That's true and worth pointing out. The question doesn't mention nested conditions.

Comment: As we don't know the correct grammar for the string, I'd err on the side of caution.

Comment: My expression can also contain underscore. like it could be value_1, value_2. Will it work there ?

Comment: @RajseGodia - The expression looks for "anything but `=`", so yes.

Comment: @RajseGodia [yes with the first one](https://regex101.com/r/MzirM3/1) and [the second one](https://regex101.com/r/JBnrPd/1) but also see potential problems in the links. Please clarify what the structure of your string would be.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for solution, my structures will be like : simply single value...i.e. 'Value_1'  , next would be mentioned above like '(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0' ......next could be like 'Value1_WaitingCaseL1 * Value2_WaitingPalletL1'

Comment: @VLAZ when my structure contain 'Value_1' it ignores.

Comment: @RajseGodia - Again, both of the above work just fine with `Value_1` and `Value_2` rather than `Value1` and `Value2`. I don't know what you mean by "it ignores." Note that we can only answer what you've included in the question. At this point, the question is well settled. If what you actually have is substantially different from what's shown, you'll need to post a new question with the actual thing you want to handle, a complete description of it, your attempt to apply the above to it, and exactly what's not working as you expect.

Comment: @RajseGodia - I've updated my answer to account for your changes to the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?<![and|or|not])`. I just updated regex in your code, please test and let me know if you have any concern.

```js
const paragraph = '(Value1==6) and (Value2==0)?1:0';
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?<![and|or|not])/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```

Comment: This fails on `(Value1==6) and (Value2==0) or (toad==0)`. It excludes anything containing only the characters `a`,`n`,`d`,`o`,`r`, or `t`

Comment: @JolonB thanks for sharing above scenario.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you do that, you end up with the same regex as the original question. It will capture `an` from the word `and` again.

Comment: Thanks @JolonB - didn't look closely enough, thought Sami Ahmed Siddiqui had changed more.